# How can I convert the date from Hijri to Gregorian? PL(sql) ..... I want to enter the Hijri date and the date of my birth

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy','nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah''') ,'dd/mm/yyyy')
from dual ;

select to_date(to_char(to_date('11/07/1443','dd/mm/yyyy','nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah'''),
                 'dd/mm/yyyy' ,'nls_calendar=''gregorian''') ,'dd/mm/yyyy')  
from dual ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing each of

1. century;
2. year-of-century;
3. month;
4. day;
5. hour;
6. minute; and
7. second

It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular format but it is stored in the Gregorian calendar.

---

#### Converting Hijri to Gregorian Calendar

> I want to enter the Hijri date

If you want to convert from a formatted string to a `DATE` data-type then use the `TO_DATE` function and the appropriate `NLS_CALENDAR` settings as you did in the question

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         '1443-07-22 09:25:30',
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
         'NLS_CALENDAR=''arabic hijrah'''
       ) AS now
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs a `DATE` data-type (with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`):

> | NOW |
> | --- |
> | 2022-02-24 09:25:30 |

If you want to **DISPLAY** the output as a string (and not as a `DATE` data-type) and explicitly set the format and specify the calendar then use `TO_CHAR` to do the formatting and conversion:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           '1443-07-22 09:25:30',
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
           'NLS_CALENDAR=''arabic hijrah'''
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
         'NLS_CALENDAR=''gregorian'''
       ) AS hijrah_to_gregorian
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | HIJRAH_TO_GREGORIAN |
> | --- |
> | 2022-02-24 09:25:30 |

---

#### The Queries in the Question

If you want them as dates in the Gregorian calendar (which is the default) then the queries in the question can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;
```

and:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         '11/07/1443',
         'dd/mm/yyyy',
         'nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah'''
       ) 
FROM   DUAL;
```

If you want the queries in the question to output a string formatted to use the Hijrah calendar then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         sysdate,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
         'NLS_CALENDAR=''arabic hijrah'''
       ) AS now
FROM   DUAL;
```

and

```sql
SELECT '11/07/1443' FROM DUAL;
```

---

#### Changing the session parameters

If you want to change the calendar in your current session (note: this will not change the calendar for any other user or any of your subsequent sessions), you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = 'Arabic Hijrah';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

If you are using a client application that formats dates based on the NLS session parameters, then:

```sql
SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SYSDATE |
> | --- |
> | 22/07/1443 09:46:54 |

and

```sql
SELECT DATE '2022-02-13' FROM DUAL;
```

*(Note: date literals are still input using the Gregorian calendar and not the current session calendar.)*

Outputs:

> | DATE'2022-02-13' |
> | --- |
> | 11/07/1443 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c043290973b4225e7976f459849d659)*